# Не обновляется переменная VueJs Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть переменная `let curLanguage = true`
При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает функция:

```
const changeLanguage = () => {
    if(curLanguage){
        curLanguage = false
    } else {
        curLanguage = true
    }
    return curLanguage
}
```

В консоли функция отрабатывает, возвращая true или false. Но при выводе её в template он как была изначально true, так и остается true. Хотелось бы узнать, что конкретно и куда нужно дописать. Благодарю за помощь)

Comment: На всякий случай, эту функцию можно сократить до `return !curLanguage`

Comment: но если я нажму на кнопку и она будет равна false, она не поменяется на true

Comment: Я про функцию, восклицательный знак `!` инвертирует булевую переменную и никакие `if`-ы там не нужны.

Comment: ну в таком случае функция всё равно отработает только 1 раз. То есть она всегда будет принимать у переменной true, и возвращать её с false. Нужно чтоб менялось значение при каждом нажатии, благодаря чему в template в v-if отрабатывало то или иное значение

Comment: Надо было чуть больше предоставить инфы, откуда переменная и как она установлена. Не помню наизусть Vue, но может это какая реактивная ссылка, и значение ей надо менять не так. ref-ссылкам, если не ошибаюсь, значение меняют через `curLanguage.value`

Comment: о, добавил ref, теперь он стал менять значение, но только почему-то 1 раз

Comment: Потому что у тебя `if(curLanguage)`, по всей видимости, пробуй тоже с `value`

Comment: ааа, теперь же проверку надо делать с .value. Спасибо Вам огромное, я читаю про ref, но так и не понял как оно должно работать. Всё работает. Спасибо ещё раз, целый час сидел мучался

Comment: Ответите тогда на этот вопрос или я сам?

Comment: И попробуй как я и говорил, мне кажется и это должно сработать `return !curLanguage.value`. Да фиг с ним вопросом.

Comment: не, не срабатывает. возвращает только false

Comment: А не срабатывает, скорее всего, потому что ты ее куда-то возвращаешь. А я думаю ее возвращать не надо - это ведь реактивная ссылка. Она сама обновляется во всем приложении. Попробуй без `return` просто так `curLanguage.value = !curLanguage.value`

Comment: но это и логично же. Есть true переменная, это отрицание срабатывает, возвращается false, но мне же надо, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку менялось значение постоянно, а не только с true на false

Comment: Да я хорошо понял что надо. Я не понял куда ты ее возвращаешь и зачем. Реактивные ссылки никуда не возвращают, на то они и реактивные - они отражают свое изменение во всем приложении.

Comment: ну как, я возвращаю значение в сам template. Есть такой атрибут как v-if, в него вписывается переменная, если переменная равняется true, тогда v-if срабатывает, в другом случае срабатывает v-else, если он есть

Comment: в данном случае есть кнопка по смене языка, то есть у блоков есть v-if="curLanguage", следовательно если curLanguage == true, блок отображается, если false, то отображается блок на другом языке, потому что у них срабатывает v-else

Answer (score 1):

Огромное спасибо Александру из комментариев за такой быстрый ответ, я понял как работать с ref().
Переменные в composition api задаются с ref(), таким образом я изменил переменную
`let curLanguage = true` в `let curLanguage = ref(true)`
А также функция стала выглядеть так:

```
const changeLanguage = () => {
    curLanguage.value = !curLanguage.value
}
```

Comment: Посмотри [этот маленький фрагмент](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-worker-n1tm9?file=/src/App.vue), как работает ref-ссылка. Я же говорю - не надо там ничего возвращать.

Comment: аа, речь про сам return? если да, то всё верно, он не нужен

Comment: дошло, боже мой, тугодум я, что ж тут поделать

Comment: нормальный такой рефакторинг получился, спасибо))

Comment: С тебя плюсик, на какой-нибудь мой ответ :)))

Comment: нажать на треугольник на коммент под этим постом? или посмотреть твои ответы на другие вопросы и там нажать треугольник?)

Comment: Да на ответы, спасибо.

Comment: Сделано, сэр! Еще раз благодарю :3